# How to add another column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

```
select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(req)))::text val 
  from (select (select ST_AsText(wkb_geometry) as wkt 
                  from (SELECT locgeog AS wkb_geometry 
                          from mt_anchor ) as foo)
             , 'Anchor' __type__,* 
          from mt_anchor ) as req;
```

> ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Comment: Your subqueries can only return one row. That means you will need an aggregation, a TOP 1 or WHERE clause so you only return 1 row.

Comment: i have only half solutions:json_agg(expression)